# jQuery 1.3.2 not working on Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

When I run my site on internet explorer 11 it falls over. Using the developer console I can trace the problem to the jQuery-1.3.2 file. The line is code causing the problem is

```
J.open(G,M.url,M.async)
```

Has anyone come accross this error before? This error is not present on any other browser or version of IE

Comment: I'm not exactly surprised that a jQuery version that's 7 major releases behind might have some issues with browsers released 4 years later. When 1.3.2 was released the latest version of IE was 7.

Comment: I am well aware of this and there is good reason why I choose to use this version.

Comment: Hmmm. Whatever your good reason is, I think you're going to have to reconsider it. What is your good reason? Perhaps we can help you think around it and find another solution.

Comment: If your good reason is an old plugin that needs this pre-historic version to keep itself running, I would work out the plugin instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This portion of jQuery is related to the XHR functionality. In older versions of Internet Explorer, and jQuery, ActiveX was leveraged to make these asynchronous requests. In modern versions of jQuery, the browser is investigated a bit further to determine whether ActiveX should be used. Additionally, modern versions of Internet Explorer won't play nicely with ActiveX XHR alternatives. Rather, the same code used for Chrome and Firefox should be used for Internet Explorer - something older jQuery builds didn't do.

You have a few options here; you can invalidate jQuery's (1.3.2, that is) understanding of what the browser is, and subsequently break much of the library not related to asynchronous requests, or you can use a more modern version of jQuery which makes far better decisions with regards to what the browser is capable of. I would suggest the later, as the former could potentially destroy any hope of jQuery making your life easier in the end.

Comment: Thanks for this, provided some clarity :)